MySQL Storage: VARCHAR vs. TEXT
I'm comparing the storage efficiency of VARCHAR and TEXT data types in MySQL 8, using the InnoDB storage engine and the default utf8mb4 character set with utf8mb4_general_ci collation. I want to determine the storage requirements for both when storing a 256-character string. While MySQL's documentation provides details on VARCHAR storage I'm unable to find equivalent information for TEXT.

For UTF8MB4 the 256-char string may occupy up to 1024 bytes. And for both datatypes the tail which exceeds 768 bytes will be stored off-page.

Note carefully the distinction between "bytes" and "chars" in Akina's comment.

In InnoDB, VARCHAR and TEXT are stored identically.
Exactly how they are stored depends on the row format for the InnoDB table. Read details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-row-format.html
The only differences between VARCHAR and TEXT are:

You can define a DEFAULT option for a VARCHAR column, but not for TEXT.

You can define a maximum length in characters for a VARCHAR column (up to 64KB). A TEXT column always allows up to 64KB, however many characters fit in that.


